# how to customize box-sizing in chakra ui?

Tags: next.js, chakra-ui

I wanna customize global style in chakra ui so that my all elements box-sizing is changed to border-box!
This is my trial. But nothing happens.

```
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react';


const overrides: object = {
  styles: {
    global: {
      '*': {
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
      },
    },
  },
};

export default extendTheme(overrides);
```

I import `extendTheme` in my `_app.tsx` file. I think this code is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Chakra's resetCSS enables `boxSizing: 'border-box'` so you don't have to do this when you extend your theme.

You can set this from the Chakra Provider `<ChakraProvider resetCSS theme={theme}>`